# Distribution of $X_t := \int^\sqrt t _0 \sqrt{2u}\; dB_u$

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_t)_{t≥0}$ be a Brownian motion. What is the (distribution of the) process $(X_t)_{t≥0}$ given by $X_t := \int^\sqrt t _0 \sqrt{2u}\; dB_u$?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Find the SDE for $X_t$ by differentiating the given integral,

$$dX_t =(\sqrt t)'\sqrt{2t}\; dB_t = dB_t$$

which yields $X_t = B_t$.

Comment: You can differentiate the integral because the integrand is a deterministic function?

Comment: @Mdoc - not because of that. $d_t\int^t(.)dB_t=(.)dB_t$ regardless.

Comment: But this is a little bit different. Here we have $d \int^{f(t)}(.)dB_t = f'(t)(.)dB_t$. So this seems to me like a version of Leibniz integral rule. That is what caught my attention. Is Leibniz integral rule valid for stochastic integrals?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**  You are adding a bunch of zero-mean normals to each other, so the result must be a zero-mean normal. can you find the variance?